# Boost not finding local installed icu

Tags: linux, boost, icu

I am trying to build libboost, 1.70.0.
I've already compiled ICU4C, and installed it locally at my `$HOME/usr`. I have it build `icu-config` as well in order to help finding it.
I have `$HOME/usr/lib` in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, and I have `$HOME/usr/bin` in my `PATH`.

I am running `bootstrap` this way:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-icu=$HOME/usr/ --prefix=$HOME/usr/
```

The output suggest that icu will be enabled. And the supplied path is saved in bjam configuration.

Later, when running

```
./b2 --reconfigure
```

it says ICU will not be used:

```
- bzip2                    : yes
- lzma                     : no
- zstd                     : no
- iconv (libc)             : yes
- icu                      : no
- icu (lib64)              : no
- native-atomic-int32-supported : yes
```

Although not critical, it is interesting it doesn't find lzma, even it being installed locally too.

I am kind of lost, with no idea what I am missing. Recompiled ICU for a couple of times, tried different approaches I found online, and nothing works. Any help is welcome.

---

Config.log shows,

```
In file included from /home/ambs/usr/include/unicode/uversion.h:30:0,
                 from libs/regex/build/has_icu_test.cpp:12:
/home/ambs/usr/include/unicode/umachine.h:340:13: error: char16_t does not name a type
     typedef char16_t UChar;
             ^
In file included from libs/regex/build/has_icu_test.cpp:12:0:
/home/ambs/usr/include/unicode/uversion.h:173:55: error: UChar does not name a type
 u_versionFromUString(UVersionInfo versionArray, const UChar *versionString);
                                                       ^
```

as well as other similar errors. I am (well, I think I am) compiling with the same compiler (that isn't in a standard path, too, but is in my path).

Answer (score 0):

While I am not understanding why bjam is not detecting correctly the compiler, if I use:

```
./bjam  cxxflags='-std=c++11'
```

then, not just I have icu, as I have C++11 features detected.